# Http version redirected to https but appeared as 200 OK

Tags: magento2, redirect, https

When I try to call a page in my browser with http:// it goes to the corresponding page with https://, which apparently looks OK. (see http://thailandfightgear.fr/gant-boxe-twins-orange for exemple)

But when i try to check the redirect status of the pages using redirect checker tool (like this one [redirectcheck.com](http://redirectcheck.com/index.php)) , it return HTTP/1.1 200 OK code instead of 301 redirect.

I don't understand why the robot cannot see the redirect. any clues ?

PS: For the redirect with `www to non-www url`, it works fine.

Comment: because you dont have 301 redirect, there is only 307

Comment: It's not even using https for me